# understanding model defined in torch7 deep learning framework

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch

I am trying to understand a deep learning model defined in torch7 framework here: [code](https://github.com/phillipi/pix2pix/blob/master/models.lua)

I am new to deep learning and torch7 framework. I have tried reading the documentation of `nn graph` module of torch, however, I don't understand what this line represents:

```
local e1 = - nn.SpatialConvolution(input_nc, ngf, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1)
```

What is happening with `= -`?

The torch tutorials which I've seen define a model using a simple straight-forward way:

```
...
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(...)
...
```

However, the code I'm referring to, uses `= -` and `-` operations which I don't understand; neither I can find any tutorial which defines a model in this manner. Please help me to understand the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative syntax to write models using the `nngraph` package. You have basically two possibilities, either using the `__call__` operator (`()`) or using the `__unm__` (unary multiplication, placing a `-` sign before an expression) and the `__sub__` (binary subtraction `-`) to make "your code looks like a data flow".

Have a look at the documentation of the `nngraph` package, this could help you understanding the syntax: https://github.com/torch/nngraph#two-hidden-layers-mlp